# Android Pasar selección de un navigation drawer un fragment

Tags: android, navigationview, listview, android-fragment

Estoy buscando la manera de pasar la selección que se hace en un menú de `Navigation Drawer` a un `fragment`, para en función de la selección cargar un `listview` con unos datos u otros.

Hasta ahora conseguí con cada selección llamar a un `fragment` distinto, pero ya que todos tienen un `listview`, me gustaría poder llamar al mismo con algún parámetro y así distinguir para cargar de una tabla u otra.

Comment: Si es únicamente un id para indicar que tipos cargar recomiendo la primera opción de mi respuesta. @JBAUER

Answer (score 1):

Como ya logras pasar a un `fragment` dependiendo de la seleccion, simplemente puedes pasar el dato asi :

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("valor", su_valor);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Donde `fragment` es al que tu quieres redireccionar.

Y cuando ya pases al `fragment` simplemente lo rescatas

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    int i = bundle.getInt(key, defaulValue);
}
```

En este ejemplo pase un dato del tipo `int` pero puedes ocupar muchos mas [Metodos de Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas es cargar un Fragment pero sus datos cambien de acuerdo a un parámetro que reciba (esto es una buena practica para no tener código/clases duplicadas.

Puedes crear un constructor estático, `newInstance()` en tu `Fragment` y este podrá recibir parámetros en base a los cuales determinarías los datos que cargaría tu `ListView` :

```
public class FragmentoEjemplo extends Fragment{

    private int tipoLista;

    public static FragmentoEjemplo newInstance(int idTipoLista){
        ExampleFragment f = new ExampleFragment();
        tipoLista = idTipoLista;
        return f;
    }
```

Al llamar instanciar tu Fragment simplemente envia el id o valor requerido para la acción que requieres dentro del Fragment:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = ExampleFragment.newInstance(12);
```

---

Incluso tu constructor estático `newInstance()` podría estar preparado para recibir más datos en un `Bundle`:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment{


    public static ExampleFragment newInstance(Bundle arguments){
        ExampleFragment f = new ExampleFragment();
        if(arguments != null){
            f.setArguments(arguments);
        }
        return f;
    }         

}
```

Los cuales enviarías de esta forma:

```
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt("idTipoLista", idTipoLista);
    arguments.putString("listaTitulo", listaTitulo);
    ExampleFragment fragment = ExampleFragment.newInstance(arguments);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, ExampleFragment.TAG);
    ft.commit();
```